# Recaptcha Image Not Displayed Correctly

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I have problem with google re-Captcha. It happens rarely, but still, sometimes the image is not displayed correctly. It misses some parts. Here is the image:

http://bit.ly/1olZoih

Here is my Html:

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">
    <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Error: Invalid code, please try again</div>

    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Please enter the code from the image above:</div>

    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />

    <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"><img id = "restart-button" src="/images/restart.png" width = "20px" height = "20px"></a></div>
</div>
```

And I apply only this css to it:

```
#recaptcha_widget{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:508px;
}

.recaptcha_only_if_image{
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #747474;
    font-size:13px;
}

#recaptcha_response_field{
    width: 233px;
    height: 21px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    float:left;
}

#recaptcha_response_field:focus{
    outline:rgb(184, 167, 130) auto 2px;
}

#restart-button{
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#recaptcha_image{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

#recaptcha_challenge_image{
    border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 5px;  
}
```

I'm not resizing the picture and it comes 300x57 px.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I cant see the image, does it has something configuration related to web.config file ? which captcha are u using? give us the link.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that now

Answer (score 0):

Try giving width to the Captcha div.

```
Width: ;
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help :(